# Using #states visible

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to make field_format visible after two select list fields have a specific values selected. I thought be not using 'or' 'xor' that both are required but its not working. this is doing the same thing as using 'or',

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'page_node_form') {
    $form['field_format']['#states'] = array(
      'visible' => array(
          array(':input[name="field_item_type[und]"]' => array('value' =>     'tv_show')),
          array(':input[name="field_extra[und]"]' => array('value' =>     'bike')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you want it to work like an xor or an or?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code. Maybe your selector is incorrect?

```
$form['main']['elem1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('1'),
  '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array('A', 'B')),
);
$form['main']['elem2'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('2'),
  '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array('A', 'B')),
);

$form['main']['elem3'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#value' => t('3'),
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      'xor',
      array(':input[name="elem1"]' => array('value' => 'A')),
      // XOR.
      array(':input[name="elem2"]' => array('value' => 'A')),
    ),
  ),
);
$form['main']['elem4'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#value' => t('4'),
);
$form['main']['elem5'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#value' => t('5'),
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="elem1"]' => array('value' => 'A'),
      ':input[name="elem2"]' => array('value' => 'A'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

And then the alter function.

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'af_aam_aam_form') {
    $form['main']['elem4']['#states'] = array(
      'visible' => array(
        array(':input[name="elem1"]' => array('value' => 'A')),
        // OR.
        array(':input[name="elem2"]' => array('value' => 'A')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```